# Custom Azure AD Role to grant the admin consent for the tenant in API permission in App Registration

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

Currently we have a built Azure AD roles which can use to grant the admin consent in API permission in App Registrations (Global Administrator/Privileged Role Administrator).

Both roles have the Highest privileges so need to create the custom role which can do only below function.

Grant the admin consent for tenant in API permission in App Registrations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-enterprise-apps) for create custom roles which guiding users to going to `Azure portal -> Azure AD -> Roles and administrators` to create the role, but it requires `Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license`.

[image]

And your requirement is `consenting for tenant in API permission`, I'm afraid you can check [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator) to comparing the permissions with the Global Admin to make sure how many permissions you want to assign exactly, and for grant api permission, I'm afraid it's `microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/managePermissionGrantsForAll.microsoft-company-admin`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the Answer, But when i am trying to create the Custom Role, I am not able to see the below permission to select. I can see this permission in Global administrator.

microsoft.directory/servicePrincipals/managePermissionGrantsForAll.microsoft-company-admin

Comment: can you search and find the `managePermissionGrantsForAll.microsoft-company-admin` like the screenshot I shared? I added a new screenshot

Comment: I added "managePermissionGrantsForAll.microsoft-company-admin" permission via CLI to  azure and made a custom role. Assigned this role to the user but still he is not able to grant the admin consent.